# How to open editor in click

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have page with 5 divs and i want to open editor on click of selected div .

And div content will come into the editor what i will do for this.

is there any j query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to edit the contents in place? Have you looked at the [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin?

Comment: Thanks Great answer but but i need an editor also.
if i will click then it will come in edit mode with text editor.

Comment: Then I would use the suggestions by Matthew! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out NicEdit or TinyMCE.  Both can be configured to edit the content in a div or any other element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CSS:
    .hidden{
       display:none;
    }

    <div id="container">
      <div id="div1" class="edit-div"><div class="editor hidden"></div><div class="content"></div></div>
      <div id="div2" class="edit-div"><div class="editor hidden"></div><div class="content"></div></div>
      <div id="div3" class="edit-div"><div class="editor hidden"></div><div class="content"></div></div>
      <div id="div4" class="edit-div"><div class="editor hidden"></div><div class="content"></div></div>
      <div id="div5" class="edit-div"><div class="editor hidden"></div><div class="content"></div></div>
    </div>

var xeditorChange = function(el)
{
  if ($(el).length>0)
  {
     $(el).find(".content")
          .empty()
          .html(editor.getText())
          .removeClass("hidden");

     $(el).find(".editor")
         .empty()
         .addClass("hidden");
  }
};

$(function(){
  $(".edit-div").click(function()
{
    xeditorChange( $("#container").find(".editing") );

    editor.addText($(this).find(".content").html());
    $(this).find(".content").addClass("hidden");
    $(this).find(".editor").removeClass("hidden");

    //show editor in  $(this).find(".editor")
});

  //on save text in editor add the html with reverse function

});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't work for me.
Do you have any other way to do this.

Comment: I do not know what editor you have, but as far as I probe the script works. You would have to adapt to the editor that you use the functions editor.getText() and editor.addText(...)